# Visual studio IDE - Import settings from code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sdk, ide

I have some add-in and I would like to load some edit settings.
Is there any way to import some visual studio settings from code?

Here some more info regarding my task:
I created an add-in which open some toolWindows. I need does windows to be dock to the VS. The only way which I was found (after a week of seeking) is to create my one Winodws Config, open the windows, arrange them as I want to. than Export the WindowLayot from VS so I can use it for next time (import them to VS).

Do anyone know better way to arrange windows to the VS DOCK?
Thank you. Leon

Comment: Are you wanting to import the settings for the entire environment or just a specific project?  (the import/export wizard within Visual Studio handles the entire environment very well, albiet not from within code directly)

Comment: I dont care if to import it to the entire env, but it must be from code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [build-tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha%28VS.80%29.aspx) with your customized setup to 'at the press of a button' set up your entire Visual Studio environment as you desire.

I believe in the end you will basically be using a tool that, among other things, imports a Visual Studio Configuration file that you have saved previously.

This would be a really long way of doing what is built-in to the Visual Studio environment if you were not going to take advantage of any of the other build functions, but since you're asking the question you likely have a need (such as setting this environment up on many computers) to do such a thing.

Because of the functionality built-in to Visual Studio and how most coding environments work, there seems to be an oversight of the capability to do exactly what you ask for.  You could consider writing your own build tool - but with the way Visual Studio works (and I may be wrong) it appears that you would be using an unnecessarily big hammer to do what a small hammer (importing a saved config file) would be fully capable of doing.

---

None of this matters if I'm misunderstanding your exact need.  Your post was a little sparse - if necessary, are there more details about what you are hoping to accomplish that would help us find a solution for you (a solution other than the solution you originally had in mind)?

Comment: Hi Ecnalyr,
Thanks for your ansewr.

Comment: I added some more info in the original question. Thanks Leon